# Concatenating two tables distributively

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I'm not 100% sure how to phrase the question, but I'm pretty much trying to do this:

say I have two tables:

table a:

```
a1
a2
```

and 
table b:

```
b1
b2
```

I want to combine them and create a table such as:

```
a1 b1
a1 b2
a2 b1
a2 b2
```

(for every row in table a, create row number of rows in table b sort of)

I figure I'd be able to do this using a loop of some sort, but I was wondering if there was any way to do this with set logic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax you're looking for is a `cross join`:

```
SELECT     a.*, b.*
FROM       a
CROSS JOIN b
```

Comment: wow, yeah, this is really easy. I'm a Java programmer so my first thought is always "LOOPS!" instead of "set logic". Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any loops.

This is a very simple task in SQL.

You can do:

```
select a.*, b.*
from a
cross join b
```

or:

```
select a.*, b.*
from a
inner join b on (1=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to loop just simple one line query would work.

```
SELECT a.*, b.* FROM a,b
```

**Note**: By Default it is cross join so no need to define keyword cross join.